# Type 1119: Access of possibly undefined property my_Object through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer

Tags: actionscript, compiler-errors, flash

I have old swf file when I add the content I got error. My file has the following code

```
if((parent && parent.parent) 
    && (parent.parent.my_Object) 
    && (parent.parent.my_Object.hasOwnProperty("InformationData")))
```

I have imported the file where the following codes are given.

```
instreamObject = EW.root.parent.parent["my_Object"];
```

where `var instreamObject:Object = null;`

How can I remove the error

`Type 1119: Access of possibly undefined property my_Object through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObjectContainer`

My old swf is working with `my_Object` but after adding some code which did not have problem I got the `undefined property my_Object` error.

How could I remove the error. Please help.

Comment: basically flash can't find `my_Object` on your `EW.root.parent.parent` which has a type of `DisplayObjectContainer`, are you sure it is there?

Comment: Yes it is there as my older compiled swf is working fine but when I add some code into it, error comes. As It already imported the content where  `instreamObject = EW.root.parent.parent["my_Object"];` is placed.